# output the char array in Xcode and Eclipse

Tags: c++, arrays, xcode, eclipse

I found that there's a difference between Xcode and Eclipse when I printed the char array.
In xcode:
[image: print char array]

the output is:
[image: output in xcode]

In Eclipse:
[image: print char array in Eclipse]

the output:
[image: output in Eclipse]

Can someone tell me why there are something followed by "qe" in Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to treat a *char array* like a *string* for printing then you need to make it *null terminated*. That means the last character needs to be `\0`.

```
char d[] = {'q', 'e', '\0'}; // NOTE: null terminator '\0'
char* b = d;
std::cout << b << std::endl;
```

Otherwise you end up printing whatever happens to be in memory after the end of the array because the *null character* tells it when to stop printing.